# My node module is no longer working after updating to Maverick

Tags: node.js, terminal, osx-mavericks

Before installing Maverick my app worked well.  After installing Maverick when i typed `nodemon app.js` in terminal it no longer worked so I reinstalled node and then 
`npm uninstall nodemon` followed by `npm install nodemon`to reinstall it.  This worked well, and nodemon now works.  Unfortunately now I have a new bug that I  can't resolve.   When uploading images in my app I get

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined`

```
        var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true }); 
        gm(target_path).size(function (err, size) {//shrinks and replaces large images
          if (size.width > 700 || size.height > 700) {  
            gm(target_path).scale(700, 700).autoOrient().write(target_path, function (err) {
              if (!err) console.log('shrunk! ');
            });
          }
        });
```

If I comment it out, and then just load up a page with an image I then get

```
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
2 Oct 17:30:21 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have uninstalled and resinstalled fs, gm, imagemagick, jquery, and just about all my modules with no success.  I have the following within `usr/local/lib/node_modules`
and within my `node_modules` directory inside my project minus node and npm.

```
 $ ls
    bcrypt-nodejs   consolidate express     fs      gm      imagemagick jquery      mongodb     node-fs     nodemon     npm
```

Still getting this:

```
/Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_11-8/routes/content.js:605
                  if (size.width > 700 || size.height > 700) {  
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
    at gm.<anonymous> (/Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_11-8/routes/content.js:605:15)
    at gm.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at gm.<anonymous> (/Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_11-8/node_modules/gm/lib/getters.js:70:16)
    at cb (/Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_11-8/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:265:16)
    at ChildProcess._spawn.proc.on.onExit (/Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_11-8/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:247:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
3 Oct 11:58:43 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

Comment: Do you have graphicsmagic installed still on your system? The `gm` module is just a wrapper around the command-line binary, so it seems like the command-line binary is no longer installed.

Comment: @mscdex I'm not sure.  How do I check and/or install it?

Comment: The command-line binary is just called `gm`, so try typing that in a terminal window and see what you get back.

Comment: `-bash: gm: command not found` that's in the project folder

Answer (score 1):

GraphicsMagick seems to have been uninstalled in the upgrade process, so you will need to reinstall it for the `gm` node module to work since it is just a simple wrapper around the command-line binary `gm`.

To install GraphicsMagick the system library and command-line utility, here are some options:

- Install via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with: `brew install graphicsmagick`
- Install via [macports](https://www.macports.org/) with: `port install graphicsmagick`
- [Download](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html), compile, and install GM manually.

Comment: so `npm uninstall gm` followed by `npm install gm` ?

Comment: It looks like I'm getting `-bash: command not found` for every module except nodemon which is the only one working

Comment: No, you have to install the GraphicsMagick software again. Whether you do that from something like homebrew, macports, or compiling and installing.

Comment: @Squirrl I didn't mean that every module has a system-wide command of the same name, it just so happens that the node module name `gm` is the same as GraphicsMagick's command-line binary's name of `gm`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you a few possible solutions to installing GraphicsMagick on your system.

Comment: I'm getting this: `brew install graphicsmagick
Error: You must 'brew link libpng freetype' before graphicsmagick can be installed`
`Squirrel$ brew link libpng freetype
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.13... 
Error: Could not symlink include/libpng16
/usr/local/include is not writable.`

Comment: $ brew install imagemagick `Warning: imagemagick-6.8.9-7 already installed, it's just not linked`

Comment: `$ brew link imagemagick
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7... 
Error: Could not symlink include/ImageMagick-6
/usr/local/include is not writable.`

Comment: ImageMagick is a different software, you want GraphicsMagick. For the `... is not writable` errors, you may need to prefix the command with `sudo`.

Comment: I did `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/include` and ran `brew doctor` and `brew update` and got it to link.  And then `npm install gm` Yet I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I did `brew install graphicsmagick` `graphicsmagick-1.3.20 already installed`